# Delete whitespaces before selected lines

Tags: vim

I have text like this:

```
This is a normal line. 
       6 spaces are before me.              //line 1 
      4 spaces are before me.               //line 2 
    3 spaces are before me.                 //line 3 
       6 spaces are before me.              //line 4 
     4 spaces are before me.                //line 5 
Another normal line.
   2 spaces are before me. But that is ok.  //line 7 
Line goes on.
```

How do I use vim to select and delete all the spaces before line 1 to line 5 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use visual line mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to select the lines I wanted, then run the substitute command on them (hitting `:` should automatically include the visual mark `'<,'>` at the start for you):

`:'<,'>s/^\s*`

This is useful when you're working and haven't figured out the line numbers. In this case as you know it's lines 2 to 6, you can do:

`:2,6s/^\s*`

A helpful option for figuring out the line numbers quickly is `set number`.

The substitute command is greedingly grabbing all whitespace (`\s*`) from the start of each line (`^\s*`), and replacing it with nothing (equivalent to `/^\s*//`).

Comment: This will also remove spaces from line 7 unless you include a better range than `%`.

Comment: In my haste to reply I misread the question. I've now updated the answer with a better range.

Comment: Thanks. Line numbers should not be used - The first solution is good. But there is a typo: 's' is missing after '>'.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick method: You can also use the `<<` command. Go to line 1 and enter `5<<` to shift lines 1-5 to the left. Repeat with the `.` command until all whitespace has disappeared. This is useful for increasing indent as well by using `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no indention defined for this file, you could use `={motion}`. If the cursor is on the first line, do <kbd>=G</kbd> to indent to the end of the file or <kbd>=}</kbd> to indent to next empty line.

To do it for this and the following 4 lines use <kbd>=4j</kbd>.